# How do I detect call forwarding in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Basically, I want to do the same thing that Google Voice does. I forward my calls to a DID number that rings my Asterisk server via IAX2, which, if it detects the call has been forwarded, sends it to voicemail. Otherwise, if the call hasn't been forwarded (and somebody has dialed the DID number), it dials my phone number and tries to reach me.

**tl;dr**: how do I detect that a call has been forwarded to my asterisk box?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this also. You want "RDNIS"

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/RDNIS

Just look at that to determine what numbers were involved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can detect if a call has been forwarded. I don't believe Google Voice can do this either.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it does -- whenever I forward the call to Google Voice, it doesn't attempt to ring my phone because it knows that it's unavailable, whereas if I call my Google Voice number the phone rings.